# Intermittent IdentityServer4 Cryptographic Error

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I have an OAuth Server that authenticates and Asp.Net (v5) API Server via IdentityServer4 token mechanisms (AspNetIdentity).

This API Server calls a 3rd-Party service on a frequent-basis.

It will be working fine; then, out of the blue it will stop working.

The error on the OAuth Server, reveal this:

dbug: IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService[0] In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration. info: IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService[0] { "Details": "Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper\u002BWindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist\

When I replublish the OAuth Server then it fixes it for some time, usually until the next day at which time it will break again; and, always with this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured the Data Protection API with a persistent key?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: No, I have not. However, I am pretty sure my Hosting Provider takes care of this.  I think I have found the issue; and it is a resource issue on my Hosting Provider's side. Thanks for your suggestion, though

Comment: It's good to always configure it when you are in production, so no cookies get invalidated IF you lose the cookie encryption key during redeployment.  (Depends on how its deployeD)

Comment: That is exactly right! My Hosting Provider fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you got it to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

It did have to do with the Cookies Security that my Hosting Provider offered. They fixed the issue.